# How to upload the data from the Redux to the database?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, redux, redux-thunk

I have a project with React frontend and Laravel backend with MySql database. I am trying to learn React and Laravel by building this project.

I am trying to put the products to the redux if the user is not signed in yet. And after the user signs in, I am trying to move the products from the Redux to the cart table in database including the user_id. If the user is signed in before adding the products to the Redux, I am trying to save the products directly in the cart table in database. Can anyone help me with my code?

amazonSlice.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from "axios";

const initialState = {
  products: [],
  userInfo:[],
  status: 'idle'
};

export const updateCartOnSignIn = createAsyncThunk('amazon/updateCartOnSignIn', async (selectItems, { getState }) => {

    const [apitoken, setapitoken] = useState('');
    useEffect(() => {
        const storedapitoken = localStorage.getItem('api_token');
        if (storedapitoken) {
            setapitoken(storedapitoken);
        }
    }, []);


    const { userInfo } = getState().amazon;
    try {
      const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/updatecart',{user_id: userInfo.id, selectItems}, {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${apitoken}`, 
          },
      });
      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
}
);

export const amazonSlice = createSlice({
  name: "amazon",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    // Actions
    addToCart: (state, action) => {
      const item = state.products.find((item) => item.id === action.payload.id)
      if(item) {
        item.quantity += action.payload.quantity
      } else { 
        state.products.push(action.payload)
      }
      
    },

    removeFromCart: (state, action) => {
      state.products = state.products.filter((item) => item.id !== action.payload)
    },

    clearCart: (state) => {
      state.products = []
      window.scrollTo({ top: 0 });
    },

    quantityIncrement: (state,action) => {
      const item = state.products.find((item) => item.id === action.payload)
      item.quantity++
    },

    quantityDecrement: (state, action) => {
      const item = state.products.find((item) => item.id === action.payload)
      if(item.quantity === 1) {
        item.quantity = 1
      } else {
        item.quantity --
      }
    }
  },
});

export const { addToCart, removeFromCart, clearCart, quantityIncrement, quantityDecrement } = amazonSlice.actions;

// Selectors - This is how we pull information from the Global store slice
export const selectItems = (state) => state.amazon.products;
export const selectTotal = (state) => state.amazon.products.reduce((total, item) => total + (item.price * item.quantity) , 0)

export default amazonSlice.reducer;
```

Product.js

```
import Image from 'next/legacy/image'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { StarIcon } from '@heroicons/react/24/solid'
import Currency from 'react-currency-formatter';
import prime from '../../images/prime.png'
import axios from 'axios';

import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { addToCart, updateCartOnSignIn, selectItems, clearCart } from '@/slices/amazonSlice';

const Product = ({ id, title, price, description, category, src }) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const itemsInCart = useSelector(selectItems);

    const [apitoken, setapitoken] = useState('');
    const [userid, setuserid] = useState('');
    useEffect(() => {
        const storedUsername = localStorage.getItem('api_token');
        const storedUserid = localStorage.getItem('userid');
        if (storedUsername && storedUserid) {
            setapitoken(storedUsername);
            setuserid(storedUserid);
        }
    }, []);


    async function clickAddToCart(e) {
        const isAuthenticated = !!apitoken;

        if(!isAuthenticated) {
            dispatch(addToCart({
                id,
                title,
                description,
                price,
                category,
                src,
                quantity: 1,
            }))
            
        } 
        else if(isAuthenticated && itemsInCart.length > 0 ) {
            try {
                    dispatch(updateCartOnSignIn);
                    dispatch(clearCart());
            } catch (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        } 
            else {
            let response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/updatecart', {id, title, price, description, category, src, quantity:1}, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${apitoken}`
                }
            })
            if(response) {
                console.log(response)   
            }

            dispatch(addToCart({
                id,
                title,
                description,
                price,
                category,
                src,
                quantity: 1,
            }))    

        }
    }


    return (
        <div className='relative flex flex-col m-5 bg-white z-30 p-10'>
            <p className='absolute -top-2 right-2 text-xs italic text-gray-400 my-3'>{category}</p>


            <img src={src} width={200} height={200} style={{ objectFit: 'contain', paddingBottom: '13px' }} alt="img" />

            <h4>{title}</h4>

            <p className='text-sm my-2 line-clamp-2'>{description}</p>

            <div className='mb-5'>
                {/* currency is USD by default */}
                <Currency quantity={price} /> 
            </div>

            <button onClick={clickAddToCart} className='mt-auto button'>Add to Basket</button>

        </div>
  )
}

export default Product
```

api.php

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->post('/user/updatecart', [ProductController::class, 'updatecart']);
```

ProductController.php

```
public function updateCart(Request $request) {
    if (Auth::check()) {
        $user_id = Auth::id();

        $existingCartItem = Cart::where('user_id', $user_id)
            ->where('product_id', $request->id)
            ->first();

        if ($existingCartItem) {
            $existingCartItem->quantity += $request->quantity;
            $existingCartItem->save();
        } else {
            $cart = new Cart();
            $cart->user_id = $user_id;
            $cart->product_id = $request->id;
            $cart->quantity = $request->quantity;
            $cart->save();
        }

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Cart updated successfully']);
    } else {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'User not authenticated'], 401);
    }
}
```

cart migration file

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('carts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('user_id');
        $table->string('product_id');
        $table->string('quantity');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `Product component`, you are correctly dispatching actions to add items to the cart in Redux. However, when the user is authenticated, you dispatch the `updateCartOnSignIn` action but do not pass any data to it. You should pass the itemsInCart array as an argument to this action so that it can be sent to the server.

Here's how you can update the clickAddToCart function in your `Product component`:

```
async function clickAddToCart(e) {
    const isAuthenticated = !!apitoken;
    const cartItems = itemsInCart.map(item => ({
        id: item.id,
        title: item.title,
        description: item.description,
        price: item.price,
        category: item.category,
        src: item.src,
        quantity: item.quantity,
    }));

    if (!isAuthenticated) {
        dispatch(addToCart({
            id,
            title,
            description,
            price,
            category,
            src,
            quantity: 1,
        }));
    } else if (isAuthenticated && itemsInCart.length > 0) {
        try {
            dispatch(updateCartOnSignIn(cartItems)); // Pass cartItems to the action
            dispatch(clearCart());
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    } else {
        try {
            const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/user/updatecart', cartItems, {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: `Bearer ${apitoken}`,
                }
            });

            if (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        } catch (error) {
            alert(error);
        }

        dispatch(addToCart({
            id,
            title,
            description,
            price,
            category,
            src,
            quantity: 1,
        }));
    }
}
```